# EFCore Not recognizing Database Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .Net Core WebApplication Project in which the Context Class is in a Class Library. If I hard code the connection string in the OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) method I can generate migrations. Since it is better to let dependency injection manage the context I would like to add this to the Startup Class. However when I do I get the following error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

**DbContext Class:**

```
public class CustomerManagerContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, long, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    public CustomerManagerContext() { }
    public CustomerManagerContext(DbContextOptions<CustomerManagerContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    //{
    //    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    //    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("SecretConnectionString");
    //}


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        builder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");
        builder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        builder.Entity<RoleClaim>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
        builder.Entity<UserToken>().ToTable("UserTokens");

    }
}
```

**Startup Class - ConfigureServices Method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CustomerManagerContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
    );

    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<CustomerManagerContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomerManagerContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

Comment: Not completely sure, but it doesn't sound right at all to me that you are using both `AddDbContext` and `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer` (and that here you are also calling `UseSqlServer`). Try commenting out the call to `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have tried commenting both out and neither one works. Its odd that If I use OnConfiguring the setup works. I have to be missing something.

Comment: You might also try removing both constructors or at least the parameter-less one

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If I remove both constructors I get the same error. If I just remove the parameter-less one I get the following error. No parameterless constructor was found on 'CustomerManagerContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'CustomerManagerContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory<CustomerManagerContext>' in the same assembly as 'CustomerManagerContext'.
PM> add-migration Initial

Comment: @Dblock247: You should not remove both `.AddDbContext` and `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer`, just `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer` one . I suspect its because both register two instances of `DbContextOptionsBuilder` and when the DI tries to resolve it via `provider.GetRequiredService<T>()` it fails when there is more than one registration. More then one registration can only be resolved via `GetRequiredServices` (plural)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bit me hard, getting errors like:

- `No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.`
- `No design-time services were found.`
- `The server was not found or was not accessible.`

But I ended up with a fairly simple solution/work-around:

- Set the default **startup-project** in your solution (or in your command line)
- in your `Startup.cs` **[add the migration-project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects)**:

  ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var myDbContextAssemblyName = typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly.GetName().Name;
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString(MyDbContext.ConnectionStringName);
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
            connectionString,
            x => x.MigrationsAssembly(myDbContextAssemblyName)));
            // do more ...
        }
  ```
- in your connection-string use the **IP-address and port-number** (inspired by [this corefx issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24175)), instead of the server-name/dns (FWIW: [query to get IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142142/sql-query-to-get-servers-ip-address)).
  So now I have this in my `appsettings.Development.json`:

  "ConnectionStrings": {
  "MyConnectionStringName": "Data Source=10.1.2.3,1433; Initial Catalog=MyCatalog; Integrated Security=SSPI"
  }

## TLDR: other suggestions

I found a lot of other suggestions, and I will mention a few that seemed interesting.  Maybe it will help someone else:

### Project-names in command-line

Mention startup-project and migration-project in command-line:

```
Update-Database -Verbose -Project x.Data -StartupProject x.Web
```

Addition (from the comments):  This also works from the dotnet CLI:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <MIGRATION_NAME> --project <DATABASE_PROJECT_DIR> --startup-project <STARTUP_PROJECT_DIR> dotnet ef database update --project <DATABASE_PROJECT_DIR> --startup-project <STARTUP_PROJECT_DIR>
```

### Migrate from code

One can also call migrations at [StartUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime)
, "*for apps with a local database*".  (I guess otherwise running on multiple nodes, may start multiple runtime migrations at the same time with concurrency issues?)

```
myDbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

### Set DbContext in Main.cs

[This EntityFrameworkCore issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12331#issuecomment-396777753) states:

> The problem is that when EF calls either `CreateWebHostBuilder` or
> `BuildWebHost` it does so without running `Main`. (This is intentional
> because EF needs to build the model and use the `DbContext` without
> starting the application.) This means that when EF invokes on of these
> methods the static `IConfiguration` property is still null--since it
> is only set in `Main`. So, you'll need to either make sure that
> `IConfiguration` is set/handled when EF calls one of these methods, or
> use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

This is not necessary for me, I guess because .Net Core 2 [loads the configuration behind the scenes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-configuration-providers).

### Use IDesignTimeDbContextFactory with environment variable

[This EntityFrameworkCore issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8332#issuecomment-392875981) states:

> The typical way to do this is to read a file, an environment variable, or similar inside `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

This seems too much a hack to me.

### DbContext-creation at design time

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) mentions:

> Some of the EF Core Tools commands (for example, the Migrations
> commands) require a derived DbContext instance to be created at design
> time in order to gather details about the application's entity types
> and how they map to a database schema.

They mention these ways to provide this design time DbContext:

- from application services: for an ASP.NET Core app as startup project:

> The tools try to obtain the `DbContext` object from the application's
> service provider. [...] The tools first try to obtain the service
> provider by invoking `Program.BuildWebHost()` [JP: or
> `CreateWebHostBuilder`] and accessing the `IWebHost.Services`
> property.  The `DbContext` itself and any dependencies in its
> constructor need to be registered as services in the application's
> service provider. This can be easily achieved by having a constructor
> on the `DbContext` that takes an instance of
> `DbContextOptions<TContext>` as an argument and using the
> `AddDbContext<TContext>` method.

- Using a constructor with no parameters

> If the `DbContext` can't be obtained from the application service
> provider, the tools look for the derived `DbContext` type inside the
> project. Then they try to create an instance using a constructor with
> no parameters. This can be the default constructor if the `DbContext`
> is configured using the `OnConfiguring` method.

- From a design-time factory

> You can also tell the tools how to create your `DbContext` by
> implementing the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface: If
> a class implementing this interface is found in either the same
> project as the derived DbContext or in the application's startup
> project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the `DbContext`
> and use the design-time factory.

Comment: Yes IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext> was this fix for me as well. Thanks I forgot to put my solution in.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. How can I call `context.Database.Migrate` post `OnConfiguring`? I have a dynamic per-tenant configuration and I want the DB to be generated once the tenant info is available. Posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110241/how-do-you-configure-the-dbcontext-when-creating-migrations-in-entity-framework/40852034#comment99320410_40852034) as well.

Comment: @Shimmy, this seems more like a new related question than a comment.
However, assuming you have a `public class MyDbContext: DbContext` you could call a separate method explicitly, e.g.: `new MyDbContext().MyMigrationMethod()`, where new (implicitly) calls `this.OnConfiguring` and `MyMigrationMethod()` should explicitly call `this.Database.Migrate()`.  
Call it after you know your tenant-dependent configuration is known and will be applied (e.g. calling it from your tenant), but before your db is used, of course.

Comment: This also works from the dotnet CLI:     `dotnet ef migrations add <MIGRATION_NAME> --project <DATABASE_PROJECT_DIR> --startup-project <STARTUP_PROJECT_DIR>`     `dotnet ef database update --project <DATABASE_PROJECT_DIR> --startup-project <STARTUP_PROJECT_DIR>`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue when I when providing options along with dbcontext while adding dbcontext to services like:-

```
services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

then I added dbcontext without options like below and it fixed the problem for me

```
services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>();
```

also I had to add OnConfiguring method to dbcontext class so the context can access the connection string:-

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=IdenDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way of doing things since I just started with core but  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680831/7802149) is an answer which explains this issue in a bit more detail

Comment: Isn't your OnConfiguring method going to get called every time a context is created and then wouldn't that jeopardize what you've setup in your services?