# Load appsettings.{envName}.json file in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, appsettings

In [prior versions of ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-program-and-startup-in-asp-net-core-2-preview1-2/) we could dynamically add appsetting.json files with the environment suffix like `appsettings.Production.json` for production environment.

Since the structure is a bit different, it seems that the configuration now got loaded in class `Program`. But we dont have the `` injected here,so I tried it myself using environment variable:

```
public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            string envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            string envConfigFile = $"appsettings.{envName}.json";

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(envConfigFile, optional: true);

            var finalConfig = config.Build();
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
                .UseConfiguration(finalConfig)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
```

The code got executed but it doesn't override my `appsettings.json` config. Let's say I have the following `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=xxx,Database=xxx, ..."
}
```

This ConnectionString is working. Now I create`appsettings.Development.json`

```
{
    "MyConnectionString": ""
}
```

and set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`. This should definitely throw an exception. But the app start correctly with the ConnectionString from `appsettings.json`.

According to [ASP.NET Core 2 configuration changes](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-configuration-changes), the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` method should itself use the new `ConfigureAppConfiguration` approach and load environment specific config by default. Also [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1) say that `appsettings.{Environment}.json` are loaded automatically. But this doesn't work and also loading it manually like this doesn't solve the problem:

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) => {
                    IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

How can I override the config using `"appsettings.{envName}.json"` pattern? I liked that cause it was handy to override env specific things in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: `CreateDefaultBuilder` *already* includes `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{environment}.json`. You don't need to add anything additional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out that I had a custom `DesignTimeDbContextFactory` class for migrations:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            string connectionString = Config.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext");
            builder.UseMySql(connectionString);

            return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Since the injection of the configratuion doesn't seem to work here (at the time I got errors for my connection strings when using default `Startup` class), I wrote some custom configuration class:

```
public class Config {
        static IConfigurationRoot config;
        static IConfigurationRoot AppConfig {
            get {
                if (config == null) {
                    config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                             .Build();
                }
                return config;
            }
        }
        public static string GetConnectionString(string name) {
            var connectionString = AppConfig.GetConnectionString(name);
            return connectionString;
        }
    }
```

So the problem was, that ASP.NET Core's default `ConfigureAppConfiguration` wasn't used for consistence. Instead my solution only loads `appsettings.json` since at the time of writing this class, no environment specific config was used.

I simply need to add loading here like this:

```
    static IConfigurationRoot AppConfig {
        get {
            if (config == null) {
                var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
                config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                         .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                         // https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs
                         .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                         .Build();
            }
            return config;
        }
    }
```

I'd appreciate it if someone has a cleaner solution here that let me use the default `ConfigureAppConfiguration` approach in EF migrations, cause it seems less error prone when using such default stuff instead of customized methods.

Comment: The solution is not clear, where and how do you use the `Config` class?

Answer (score 4):

According to docs, the JSON Configuration Provider should automatically load twice in [ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#json-configuration-provider) (and 
[ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#json-configuration-provider))
when using `CreateDefaultBuilder` (so move your code from the separate `ConfigurationBuilder`).

> AddJsonFile is automatically called twice when you initialize a new
>   WebHostBuilder with CreateDefaultBuilder. The method is called to load
>   configuration from:
>
> - *appsettings.json* – This file is read first. The environment version of the file can override the values provided by the *appsettings.json* file.
> - *appsettings.{Environment}.json* – The environment version of the file is loaded based on the *IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName*.

Their example:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            config.AddJsonFile(
                "config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
```

(If you want to use connection strings from your startup (UI MVC) project, for adding migrations in a different migrations project you may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221389/efcore-not-recognizing-database-provider/55066399#55066399).)

Answer (score 2):

[Environment variable Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rvmZ.png)

Based on Enviroment Variables settings we can use appsettings.environment.json file as config file

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Configuration = builder.Build();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your build settings. If you want your project to load an specific environment then you should specify to the compiler wish environment settings you want to be loaded.

I hope it helps. 
Good luck.

Comment: I already changed `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to production. On startup the app confirms that: `Hosting environment: Production`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your solution in visual studio 2017c click on the solution, in menu click properties > build and you’ll see That environment variable has already been created for the environment named Development.  If you override that value  within the properties page  for your given web project ,  it will  pull the environment variables from the app environment specific app settings .  I would also just keep your web host builder default code if your version is 2.1 or above

Comment: I already changed `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to production. On startup the app confirms that: `Hosting environment: Production`. But also when using the default web host builder (I'm using 2.1), the environment specific config is not loaded.

Comment: Make sure you dont have a machine wide environment variable set, that will take higher precidence if it does exists. There is no reason why the config would not work as expected unless you take matters into your own hands and change Program.cs CreateWebHostBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CreateDefaultBuilder()` which should provide you with the configuration settings you want (as in the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup)). Note that if you are running on Linux it is case sensitive - if the file name has a capital P for Production, the value of the environment variable must as well. Also, check you have the files in the correct directory - print the value of `Directory.CurrentDirectory()` at runtime. This is where they should be.

If this works but you don't actually want a default builder, just copy the parts you need from [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/f245512f6e68d65309b65528d479f32b34c67718/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs).